# Show that the number of elements of a finite set is well-defined.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given the following definition:

A set $A$ is finite if it is empty or there are $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and a 1-1 onto function $f:\{1,...,n\}\to A$. In the first case we say that $A$ has $0$ elements, while in the second we say $A$ has $n$ elements. We say that $A$ is infinite if it is not finite.

To show that the number of elements of a finite set is well defined, we have to prove the following:

$(1)$ For all $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a 1-1 onto function $f:\{1,...,n\} \to \{1,...,k\}$ if and only if $n=k$.

I intuitively understand why it is true. But I am having a hard time proving it rigorously. I have also been told that it is best proved by induction. Can you please help provide a proof for that statement?

Comment: It looks like what you're showing that the _size_ of a finite set is well-defined, not that its _elements_ are.

Comment: As a supplement to the answers already posted (and sorry to toot my own horn), you might want to look at Theorem 4.1.35 [here](https://infinitedescent.xyz/dl/infdesc.pdf) (page 188), and Section 4.1 more generally - only (2) is proved explicitly, but (3) has a similar proof and (4) is an immediate consequence of (2) and (3).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Updated the question. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch:**

Hopefully you know that if $n\ne k$, then one of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $\{1,2,\ldots, k\}$ is a proper subset of the other.

Now prove by induction on $n$ that a function from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to a proper subset of itself cannot be injective.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what the base case and the induction step would be? I still don't see it.